# Using Mailgun as a listserv

Tags: email, mailgun

I'm trying to implement a basic listserv using Mailgun. The behavior I'm trying to replicate is like Google Groups.

Which email headers should be set to replicate the following functionality:
* to address listed as the mailing list, not the individual
* from address listed as the original sender

If I use the send to mailing list functionality in Mailgun, the emails are not addressed to the group but rather to the recipients individually. I could instead pull the list and email the recipients manually but I'm not sure which headers to set to achieve the above.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you can use this. 
https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-mailinglists.html#access-levels

Answer (score 0):

As Prabu pointed out you should set the Access Level on the mailing list to "members" which allows replies to emails between members of the list.  "readonly" is the default and that won't do what you need.

"access_level": "everyone" will show on a mailing list that you query in the api when the setting is where you need it.

Comment: No it actually doesn't do what I want because it doesn't allow me to modify the emails sent. I want to add a footer and a prefix to the subject line. If I set it to `members` then everyone gets the original plain email in addition to the one I modified and re-sent. I need to know what headers they are setting automatically with the `members` mode so I can set them myself

Comment: So you want each email sent to the list to be delivered twice to everyone?  First one delivered exactly as sent but the second one you want to modify the subject line and the content (add footer)?  Or you just want to deliver once to everyone after modifying each email reply?

Comment: I only want the modified one delivered but there's no way to use `members` mode and stop the original from going through